# How to get the object properties using AngularJS and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I think it is not a big problem but I can't find any solution for this. Using Angular I want to display item details from database. I have my server side code that is searching for ID and returning Json. Then in Angular controller I get the data, single record. But I can't display any informations about this. It only works when I use ng-repeat but that's not the case. There is no point to use ng-repeat when I have just one single record.

//

It shouldn't be something like this?

```
$scope.item = { name: 'jack', city: 'sydney' };
```

And in my view

```
{{item.name}}
```

But with my single record from database it's not working. Do you have any idea what is wrong  here? Or maybe I'm missing something? Here is my code

ASP.NET MVC Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetGame(int id, string gameName)
{
    var getById = GetGameById(id, gameName);
    if (getById != null)
    {
        using (KeyGameContext dbx = new KeyGameContext())
        {
            dbx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var getGame = dbx.Games.Find(id);
            return Json(getGame, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(null);
    }
}

public Game GetGameById(int gid, string gName)
{
    return db.Games.Find(gid);
}
```

AngularJS code:

```
   $http({
       url: '/Genre/GetGame',
       params: {
           id: $routeParams.id,
           gameName: $routeParams.gameName
       },
       method: 'get'
   }).then(function (data) {
       $scope.getGame = data;
       console.log(data);
   });
```

And here is some informations about this record from the console

[image]

Comment: Aren't you able to access the game data via {{getGame.data}} in your template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea this throws people off when they first start using $http. Try this

```
$http({
       url: '/Genre/GetGame',
       params: {
           id: $routeParams.id,
           gameName: $routeParams.gameName
       },
       method: 'get'
   }).then(function (data) {
       $scope.getGame = data.data;
       console.log(data);
   });
```

What gets passed into your "then" promise function is the *response* object, which contains information about the http request in addition to your data. The actual data object is stored at .data

So I usually write mine as

```
$http({
       url: '/Genre/GetGame',
       params: {
           id: $routeParams.id,
           gameName: $routeParams.gameName
       },
       method: 'get'
   }).then(function (response) {
       $scope.getGame = response.data;
       console.log(data);
   });
```

Comment: Wow, nice thanks. Now it's working. It's not my first time but good to know about this.

Answer (score 0):

just replace your code

```
 $scope.getGame = data;
```

to

```
 $scope.getGame = data.data;
```

"Happy Coding"